# GridDB Error CM_NOT_SUPPORTED - How to Check and Set Specified Index Type for a Column?

Tags: indexing, error-handling, nosql, configuration-files, griddb

I'm currently working with GridDB, and I've encountered the "CM_NOT_SUPPORTED" error. From my research, it seems to be related to checking whether a specified index type can be set for a specified column.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

I'm looking for guidance on how to check whether a specified index type can be set for a particular column in GridDB. Additionally, I would like to know if there are specific configuration files or commands I should be exploring to address the "CM_NOT_SUPPORTED" error. Ideally, I'm seeking assistance and examples on how to set the index type for a column to resolve this issue.